# Image size for defaultSrc image - React Native

Tags: react-native

I need help on the following code.

```
<Image
    defaultSource={require('../../assets/avatar_user.png')}
    source={{ uri: props.useravatar }}
    style={{ height: 40, width: 40, resizeMode: "cover", borderRadius: 3 }} />
```

The defaultSource image displays itself very small. The tag style has no effect.

Anyone can help?
Thanks.

While the image is loading, the default image has a small size.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/defaultimage-size):

```js
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';

// You can import supported modules from npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

// or any files within the Snack
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Card>
        <Image
          defaultSource={require('./assets/snack-icon.png')}
          style={{
            height: 140,
            width: 140,
            resizeMode: 'cover',
            borderRadius: 3,
          }}
        />
        <Image
          defaultSource={require('./assets/snack-icon.png')}
          style={{
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            resizeMode: 'cover',
            borderRadius: 3,
          }}
        />
      </Card>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```